# vBulletin - implement with other PHP sites: Session login not detected

Tags: php, session, cookies, vbulletin

**vBulletin version: 3.8.7 Patch Level 2**

I am using this code to work with vBulletin cookies in my other subdomain. I mean: forum.mysite.com, myscript.mysite.com.

```
function get_session($hash){

    $db = new DB("settings.forum.ini.php"); 
    $ip = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), 0, 4 - 1));
    $newidhash = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $ip);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM session WHERE sessionhash = :hash LIMIT 1";
    $row = $db->query($query, array("hash"=>$hash));

    if(isset($row[0]['userid'])){       
        $sessionhash = $row[0]['sessionhash'];
        $idhash = $row[0]['idhash'];
        $userid = $row[0]['userid'];
        $lastactive = $row[0]['lastactivity'];
        $db->closeConnection();
        return ($idhash == $newidhash && (time() - $lastactive) < 900) ? $userid : false;
    }
    $db->closeConnection();
    return false;   
}


function get_cookie($id, $pass){

    $db = new DB("settings.forum.ini.php"); 

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = :id LIMIT 1";
    $row = $db->query($query, array("id"=>$id));
    if(isset($row[0])){
        $dbpass = $row[0]['password'];
        // vb might change the salt from time to time. can be found in the /includes/functions.php file
        if(md5($dbpass.COOKIE_SALT) == $pass){
      $db->closeConnection();
            return $id;
        }
    }
  $db->closeConnection();
    return false;   
}




function check_login_cookie(){
        $return  = false;
    if(isset($_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX.'userid']) && isset($_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX.'password'])){
        if(get_cookie($_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX.'userid'], $_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX.'password'])){
            $return = $_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX.'userid'];
        }
    }
    if($return !== false){
        return $return;
    }
    if(isset($_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX.'sessionhash'])){
        $return = get_session($_COOKIE[COOKIE_PREFIX.'sessionhash']);
    }
    return $return;
}


function user_info($id){
    $db = new DB("settings.forum.ini.php");
    $query = "SELECT lastactivity,username,userid,membergroupids,usergroupid FROM user WHERE userid = :id LIMIT 1";
  $return = $db->row("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = :id LIMIT 1", array("id"=>$id));
  $db->closeConnection();
    return $return;
}


function check_login(){
  if($li = check_login_cookie()){
    $uinfo = user_info($li);

    $db = new DB("settings.forum.ini.php");
    $q_lastactivity = "UPDATE user SET lastactivity = :time WHERE userid = :id LIMIT 1";
    $db->query($q_lastactivity, array("time"=>time(), "id"=>$li));

    if((time() - $uinfo['lastactivity']) > 900){
      $q_lastvisit = "UPDATE user SET lastvisit = :la WHERE userid = :id LIMIT 1";
      $db->query($q_lastvisit, array("la"=>$uinfo['lastactivity'], "id"=>$li));
    }
    $db->closeConnection();
  }
  return $li ? $uinfo : false;
}
```

When I tick "Remember Me" my script works and detects login, but with using session it won't login (by not logging in I mean the forum detects login but the script doesn't).

Then I checked the ***session*** table and it was empty, though the nulled version I used for test works with this.

Comment: I gave up on doing things like this and decided to use vBulletin's codes themselves ^_^

like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6078116/2473295

But still if there is a way to fix this I will thank you for sharing it with me :)

(and I will not post this as the right answer because it's not)